# How to target images placed by a for loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I've created a table using entirely JavaScript.

The table consists of 3 columns, where one of the columns contains only images in each of the rows. I'm trying to make it where when the user clicks one of the images in the columns, it toggles between two images.

I would have an idea of how to do this if it was just one image assigned to a variable, but since these images were placed by a for loop into a table, there doesn't seem to be any easy way to target them.

How do I do this? I've heard to use the onClick function, and I tried that first, without any success. Here's what my code looks like for that:

```
var books=[
    {title:'Six Easy Pieces: Essentials of Physics By Its Most Brillant Teacher',
    author:' Richard P. Feynman',
    alreadyRead:false
    },
    {title:'Astrophysics for People In A Hurry',
    author:'Neil deGrasse Tyson',
    alreadyRead:true
    },
    {title:'Pet Semtary',
    author:'Stephan King',
    alreadyRead:true
    },
    {title:'The Poisonwood Bible',
    author:'Barbara Kingsolver',
    alreadyRead:true
    },
    {title:'The Name Of The Wind',
    author:'Patrick Rothfuss',
    alreadyRead:true
    }
    ];
    
    //creating table
    var bookTable = document.createElement('table');
      bookTable.style.width = '75%';
      bookTable.setAttribute('border', '3px');
    //creating head of table
      var thead = document.createElement('thead');
      var htr1 = document.createElement('tr');
        
            var htd = document.createElement('td');     
            var htd2 = document.createElement('td');
            var htd3 = document.createElement('td');
            htd.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Title'));
            htd2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Author'));
            htd3.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Read?'));
    
            htr1.appendChild(htd)
            htr1.appendChild(htd2)
            htr1.appendChild(htd3)
    
        thead.appendChild(htr1);
            bookTable.appendChild(thead);
    
    //creating body
      var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
      for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        
            var td = document.createElement('td');     
            var td2 = document.createElement('td');
            var td3 = document.createElement('td');
    
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(books[i].title ));
            td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(books[i].author ));
    //adding images for read and not read
            if(books[i].alreadyRead){
                var image= document.createElement('img');
                image.src="images/check.png";
                image.style.width="50px";
                image.style.height="50px";

                image.addEventListener("click", function (event)
                {
                  var selectedImage = event.target;

                  if (selectedImage.src == "images/check.png")
                  {
                    selectedImage.src = "images/xmark.jpg";
                  }
                  else if (selectedImage.src == "images/xmark.jpg")
                  {
                    selectedImage.src = "images/check.png";
                  }
                });
              
                td3.appendChild(image);
            }
            else{
                var image= document.createElement('img');
                image.src="images/xmark.jpg";
                image.style.width="50px";
                image.style.height="50px";

                image.addEventListener("click", function (event)
                {
                  var selectedImage = event.target;

                  if (selectedImage.src == "images/check.png")
                  {
                    selectedImage.src = "images/xmark.jpg";
                  }
                  else if (selectedImage.src == "images/xmark.jpg")
                  {
                    selectedImage.src = "images/check.png";
                  }
                  });
              
                td3.appendChild(image);
    
            }
    
    
    
            tr.appendChild(td)
            tr.appendChild(td2)
            tr.appendChild(td3)
    
        
        tbdy.appendChild(tr);
      }
      bookTable.appendChild(tbdy);
      document.body.appendChild(bookTable)
    
    //changing styles
      document.head.innerHTML += `
      <style>
        thead {
          background-color: grey; 
          font-weight: bold;
          text-align: center;
    
        }    
      </style>`;
```

Comment: How are you adding the listener for a click on the img elements? Could you show us the relevant part of your for loop?

Comment: Could you make a code snippet in your question with the relevant parts of your html and javascript? Then it would be easy for us to run and reproduce the issue

Comment: I've updated the question with all of my code

Comment: @A_A tagging you incase you don't get notification

Comment: @AHaworth Tagging for notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event listener is being entered just fine.

The problem is that the src you are getting back is a full URL not just the bit that you put in your src.

You need to test that the elements you put in the src are indeed within that complete image address.

A quick (if slightly dirty) way to do this is to use indexOf - e.g.

```
(selectedImage.src.indexOf('images/check.png') != -1)
```

So your code stays exactly as it is except for the tests to see what to change the image to are replaced by the above and equivalent for the other image:

```
<script>
var books=[
    {title:'Six Easy Pieces: Essentials of Physics By Its Most Brillant Teacher',
    author:' Richard P. Feynman',
    alreadyRead:false
    },
    {title:'Astrophysics for People In A Hurry',
    author:'Neil deGrasse Tyson',
    alreadyRead:true
    },
    {title:'Pet Semtary',
    author:'Stephan King',
    alreadyRead:true
    },
    {title:'The Poisonwood Bible',
    author:'Barbara Kingsolver',
    alreadyRead:true
    },
    {title:'The Name Of The Wind',
    author:'Patrick Rothfuss',
    alreadyRead:true
    }
    ];
    
    //creating table
    var bookTable = document.createElement('table');
      bookTable.style.width = '75%';
      bookTable.setAttribute('border', '3px');
    //creating head of table
      var thead = document.createElement('thead');
      var htr1 = document.createElement('tr');
        
            var htd = document.createElement('td');     
            var htd2 = document.createElement('td');
            var htd3 = document.createElement('td');
            htd.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Title'));
            htd2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Author'));
            htd3.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Read?'));
    
            htr1.appendChild(htd)
            htr1.appendChild(htd2)
            htr1.appendChild(htd3)
    
        thead.appendChild(htr1);
            bookTable.appendChild(thead);
    
    //creating body
      var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
      for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        
            var td = document.createElement('td');     
            var td2 = document.createElement('td');
            var td3 = document.createElement('td');
    
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(books[i].title ));
            td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(books[i].author ));
    //adding images for read and not read
            if(books[i].alreadyRead){
                var image= document.createElement('img');
                image.src="images/check.png";
                image.style.width="50px";
                image.style.height="50px";

                image.addEventListener("click", function (event)
                {
                  var selectedImage = event.target;alert(selectedImage.src);

                  if (selectedImage.src.indexOf('images/check.png') != -1)
                  {alert();
                    selectedImage.src = "images/xmark.jpg";
                  }
                  else if (selectedImage.src.indexOf("images/xmark.jpg") != -1)
                  {
                    selectedImage.src = "images/check.png";
                  }
                });
              
                td3.appendChild(image);
            }
            else{
                var image= document.createElement('img');
                image.src="images/xmark.jpg";
                image.style.width="50px";
                image.style.height="50px";

                image.addEventListener("click", function (event)
                {
                  var selectedImage = event.target;

                  if (selectedImage.src == "images/check.png")
                  {
                    selectedImage.src = "images/xmark.jpg";
                  }
                  else if (selectedImage.src == "images/xmark.jpg")
                  {
                    selectedImage.src = "images/check.png";
                  }
                  });
              
                td3.appendChild(image);
    
            }
    
    
    
            tr.appendChild(td)
            tr.appendChild(td2)
            tr.appendChild(td3)
    
        
        tbdy.appendChild(tr);
      }
      bookTable.appendChild(tbdy);
      document.body.appendChild(bookTable)
    
    //changing styles
      document.head.innerHTML += `
      <style>
        thead {
          background-color: grey; 
          font-weight: bold;
          text-align: center;
    
        }    
      </style>`;
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you build your table add one listener to the `table` element. This method uses [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) - when you click on an element inside the table the event "bubbles up" the DOM and it caught by the listener on the parent element. A check to see if the target element is an image is all that's needed.

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

// Build the table
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const img = 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff';
  table.innerHTML += `<tr><td><img src="${img}" /></td></tr>`;
}

// Add a listener
table.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {

  // Extract the nodeName and src from the element
  // that was clicked on
  const { nodeName, src } = e.target;

  // If the element is an image swap the images
  if (nodeName === 'IMG') {
    if (src.split('/')[4] === '000') {
      e.target.src = 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/aaa/000';
    } else {
      e.target.src = 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table />
```

Comment: Your example works well because the full URL is set, not a relative one as in the question.

Comment: None of that extra code was in the question when I wrote my answer. @AHaworth.